# Java - Drawing Images Basically

Tags: java, python, image, drawing, imageobserver

I've come from Python to Java and am a bit confused. My main question is how to draw an image. I've looked on the oracle site but even when copy - pasting their code it didn't work. Here is what I had (excluding imports):

```
public class ImageTesting{

public void main(String[] args){
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Volumes/Data/Users/me/Desktop/Button Img.png"));
    Graphics g = null;
    g.drawImage(img, 100, 100, this);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Image Loading Failed");
}}}
```

The line I'm having problems is the g.drawImage(img, 100, 100, this); and complains about not having an image observer. It confuses me that that same line works in another code I have but works :/ What am I missing??!

Comment: g.drawImage is null which is None in python, how can you expect even in python, that you can call a method on None/null?

Comment: The main problem you have, is that you first have to create something to draw this image to. So have a look at the java "window toolkits" awt, swing or javafx. Create such a java window and then add your Image to it.

Comment: Your main problem is that you're trying to code without first looking at some tutorials. This is well explained and all easily found with just a little effort.

Comment: To Quant - The null was a recommendation by Eclipse To Hovercraft - I got the code that's working from a tutorial but this side of things was only vaugely explained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something to display your image on.

The simplest method would be to use a `JLabel`, see [How to use labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for mor examples

You need a window to display the label, see [How to create GUIs with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for details

If, for some reason, you absolutely must paint the image manually, you will need to extend from something that is paintable, like `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method.

See [How to perform custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details